# JQuery JsTree: jstree is not rendering properly in browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jstree

I am working on a Jstree with context menu plugin but there are few issues.

This is how my tree is getting rendered in browser(tested in both chrome as well as mozilla).

[image]

**but I want my jstree to be like this** http://jsfiddle.net/govi20/cnbsfkx8/1/ 
There is not a single error on chromeDev console as well as firebug console.

**HTML mark-up**

```
<link href="http://medialize.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/src/jquery.contextMenu.css">
  <link href="rhttp://static.jstree.com/3.0.8/assets/dist/themes/default/style.min.css">
  <link href="http://static.jstree.com/3.0.8/assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="jstree1">

    </div>
</body>
```

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function demo_create() {
            var ref = $('#jstree1').jstree(true),
                sel = ref.get_selected();
            if(!sel.length) { return false; }
            sel = sel[0];
            sel = ref.create_node(sel, {"type":"file"});
            if(sel) {
                ref.edit(sel);
            }
        };
        function demo_rename() {
            var ref = $('#jstree1').jstree(true),
                sel = ref.get_selected();
            if(!sel.length) { return false; }
            sel = sel[0];
            ref.edit(sel);
        };
        function demo_delete() {
            var ref = $('#jstree1').jstree(true),
                sel = ref.get_selected();
            if(!sel.length) { return false; }
            ref.delete_node(sel);
        };
        function getJSON()  {
        //    var v = $('#data').jstree(true).get_json('#', {flat:true});
            var v = $('#jstree1').jstree(true).get_json('#', { 'flat': true });
            var mytext = JSON.stringify(v);
            console.log("tree=> "+mytext);
         }

        $(document).ready(function(){
          $('#jstree1').jstree({
                "core" : {
                    "check_callback" : true,
                    "themes": {
                      "name": "default-dark",
                      "dots": true,
                      "icons": true
                  },
                  "themes" : {
                      "theme" : "apple"
                },
                    'data' : [
                            'Simple root node',
                            {
                                'id' : 'node_2',
                                'text' : 'Root node with options',
                                'state' : { 'opened' : true, 'selected' : true },
                                'children' : [ { 'text' : 'Child 1' }, 'Child 2']
                            }
                        ]
                },
                "plugins" : [ "themes","contextmenu","dnd" ]
            });
      });
    </script>

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
        <script src="http://static.jstree.com/3.0.8/assets/dist/jstree.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://medialize.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/src/jquery.contextMenu.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function demo_create() {
            var ref = $('#jstree1').jstree(true),
                sel = ref.get_selected();
            if(!sel.length) { return false; }
            sel = sel[0];
            sel = ref.create_node(sel, {"type":"file"});
            if(sel) {
                ref.edit(sel);
            }
        };
        function demo_rename() {
            var ref = $('#jstree1').jstree(true),
                sel = ref.get_selected();
            if(!sel.length) { return false; }
            sel = sel[0];
            ref.edit(sel);
        };
        function demo_delete() {
            var ref = $('#jstree1').jstree(true),
                sel = ref.get_selected();
            if(!sel.length) { return false; }
            ref.delete_node(sel);
        };
        function getJSON()  {
        //    var v = $('#data').jstree(true).get_json('#', {flat:true});
            var v = $('#jstree1').jstree(true).get_json('#', { 'flat': true });
            var mytext = JSON.stringify(v);
            console.log("tree=> "+mytext);
         }

        $(document).ready(function(){
          $('#jstree1').jstree({
                "core" : {
                    "check_callback" : true,
                    "themes": {
                      "name": "default-dark",
                      "dots": true,
                      "icons": true
                  },
                  "themes" : {
                      "theme" : "apple"
                },
                    'data' : [
                            'Simple root node',
                            {
                                'id' : 'node_2',
                                'text' : 'Root node with options',
                                'state' : { 'opened' : true, 'selected' : true },
                                'children' : [ { 'text' : 'Child 1' }, 'Child 2']
                            }
                        ]
                },
                "plugins" : [ "themes","contextmenu","dnd" ]
            });
      });
    </script>
```

please suggest me the changes.

Comment: can you please tell me how you want your output should be?

Comment: my issue is with GUI i.e CSS. 1) check this  http://jsfiddle.net/govi20/cnbsfkx8/1/ it's showing tree with folder icon etc. 2) and now check image in my question.  JSFiddle is displaying it properly but browser is not displaying it properly.

Comment: I am not understanding exactly what GUI output your require.Please give me some image of the required output.

Comment: http://oi60.tinypic.com/25pn4a1.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
<link href="rhttp://static.jstree.com/3.0.8/assets/dist/themes/default/style.min.css">
```

Use this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://static.jstree.com/3.0.8/assets/dist/themes/default/style.min.css">
```

Notice the missing "r" in the beginning of the URL - it is a typo.

But keep in mind hotlinking like this is frowned upon - jstree.com is not a CDN, you can use a real CDN:

```
http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.0.8/themes/default/style.min.css
http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.0.8/jstree.min.js
```

I will even recommend you use 3.1.1 which is fully backward compatible with 3.0.8, but has a lot of bug fixes.

Comment: changed CDN and removed typo error,still style.css not getting applied.

Comment: Use your developer tools - the network panel - do you see any requests that fail to load, or any JS errors? I doubt it could be the reason - but also include jstree's CSS after the bootstrap CSS.

Comment: Yes style.min.css is not loading.I tried to attach css from local disk still I am facing same issue. Have a look at network panel http://oi61.tinypic.com/vmwqyt.jpg

Comment: You are missing rel="stylesheet" on the link tag - I updated my answer (just add rel="stylesheet" to the link tag).

Comment: huhhh silly mistake!! Thanks for helping me out as well as providing good library.

Answer (score -2):

**Replace this line :**

```
<link
 href="rhttp://static.jstree.com/3.0.8/assets/dist/themes/default/style.min.css">
```

**With this line :**

```
<link href="http://static.jstree.com/3.0.8/assets/dist/themes/default/style.min.css">
```

Comment: How is this answer different from the answer above yours?